# how to change the link in the wordpress email with newpassword?

Tags: wordpress

how to change the link in the wordpress email with newpassword?
this information we get when we click on forgot password.

```
username : admin
password : admin
http://www.example.com/wp-login.php
```

here i want to change this url "http://www.example.com/wp-login.php" and set my own url... how can i do?

some reference code:

```
if ( !function_exists('is_user_logged_in') ) :function is_user_logged_in() {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the retrieve_password_message filter

```
function someFunction($message, $key){

}

add_filter('retrieve_password_message', 'someFunction');
```

You would then have to use the "someFunction" function to parse the $message variable and change the link.

The message variable contains the entire message. So you could simply trim the message based on the number of characters then tack on your new link...

HTH
(Untested)

Answer (score 0):

Using hooks would be my first thought so that you wouldn't have to edit any core files, however I have used the [SB Welcome Email Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/welcome-email-editor/) plugin a couple times for this exact reason. Their are a couple plugins like this out their and they are fairly light weight and allow full customization of all Wordpress generated emails.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a plugin such as Theme My Login, which does everything for you.

Editing core wordpress files is never a good idea, when updating wordpress, you'll loose all your work.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply follow steps if you want to edit your code file.

Go to your wordpress folder. Look for the following files:

```
 1. /wp-login.php 
 2. /includes/functions.php
```

Change the all the codes which contains `wp-login.php` into your custom URL.

for example:  `admin.php`  or `client-login.php`

Now you can changed your login/signup URL into your custom URL.

Known issue:  You can find some database error if you make any mistakes. Just refresh the page and try with the customized Url it will work...

Example site I used here : http://androideveloper.com/admin.php  from  http://androideveloper.com/wp-login.php

Cheers.

Comment: It is never a good idea to modify the WordPress Core. Changing the password reset message can be done using hooks, like 'retrieve_password_message' that are in the core. See aphill70's suggestion below.